# Magento 2 Catalogsearch Page Empty when i search Something

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I'm hardly puzzled after searching there is always empty page. i have lot of iphones but when i search it shows there is nothing.

any advice highly highly admired.

https://cellphonepartscanada.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=iphone

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that you have a third party module interfering in your search results or template or similar as you can see there are results when the autosuggestions load, also I don't think the route **autosearch/index/ajaxgetproduct** is a default magento route

[image]

Comment: what i should do i should disable module how i can?

Comment: Hey, is the issue resolved? When hit the above url , I could see the results